# How to create dates with variables from a form post?

Tags: php, date, runtime

Is it possible to create dates with variables from the post? To goal is to select a date range based on a form. Here's what I have so far:

```
<?php 

 include 'inc/connect.php';
 
 if(isset($_POST['rapport-taxes']))
  {

   $year=$_POST['year'];

   $Q2_start_create=date_create($year"-04-01");
   $Q2_end_create=date_create($year"-06-30");

   $Q2_start=date_format($Q2_start_create,"Y/m/d");
   $Q2_end=date_format($Q2_end_create,"Y/m/d");


   $test="SELECT * FROM devis where `fp_date` > '$Q2_start' and `fp_date` < '$Q2_end'";

   $query=mysqli_query($conn, $test);
    
   echo $query;

 }

?>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It will be great to share errors also, that helps to find the issue.

Comment: Yes it is possible, you may see https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_date_create.asp

Answer (score 0):

There can be hundreds of way but I am just helping you in what you are doing.
You missed concatenation of year, in the below line.

```
$Q2_start_create=date_create($year"-04-01");
//$year and "-04-01", to concatinate both you need to put a .
```

See the below code, run it once. echo is just to check so remove it later.

```
$year="2005";

$Q2_start_create=date_create($year."-04-01");

$Q2_start=date_format($Q2_start_create,"Y/m/d");

echo $Q2_start;
```

Answer (score -1):

PHP doesn't enforces date datatype. date_format(); will be returning string so you could just build a string and pass it to the query as long as the code you have posted is the only thing you want to get done.

```
<?php 
include 'inc/connect.php';
if(isset($_POST['rapport-taxes']))
{
$year=$_POST['year'];
$Q2_start= $year . "/04/01";
$Q2_end= $year . "/06/30";
$test="SELECT * FROM devis where `fp_date` > '$Q2_start' and `fp_date` < '$Q2_end'";
$query=mysqli_query($conn, $test);
echo $query;
}
?>
```